# combine CompositeItemProcessor and CompositeItemWriter in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a scenario that following below steps:

1. The reader will get a list A from table A. 

2. The processor processes list A to return object A and MimeMessage. 

3. The writer writes object A into table B and use MimeMessage to send mail.

Could I use CompositeItemProcessor and CompositeItemWriter for my scenario above? If yes, how can I set the output object in Step configuration and how to define which ItemWriter for send mail will take MimeMessage and ItemWriter for insert database will take object A.

Are there any better solutions for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to define which ItemWriter for send mail will take MimeMessage or ItemWriter for insert database will take object A.

You can use a [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html). This composite writer uses a `Classifier` to classify items (Type A or MimeMessage in your case) and calls one of the delegate writers for each type.

Comment: Im so sorry, but I have edited my question that item from list A should be used in both cases insert database AND send mail. However, ClassifierCompositeItemWriter just return insert database or  send mail

Comment: and how about the format of <I,O> chunk() in step configuration. Because for insert case, it might be <Customer,Customer> chunk() but it is <Customer,MimeMessage> chunk() for sending mail. How can I combine them?

Comment: ok that's different. When you say `The processor processes list A to return object A and MimeMessage. `: the processor cannot return two objects. You can make the processor create a MimeMessage and set it on object A. Is that an option for you? That way, the processor enriches each item with a MimeMessage and then a composite writer would write items to the db and send them via email. If this is what you are looking for, I can help with a code example. Otherwise, please explain with an example what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yes, that is what I am looking for. Could you give me some examples please ?

Comment: please have a look at my source code in https://github.com/duyetphamm/springbatch. I have tried your idea and it works. However, the performance is quite low (for send mail and itemReader). Could you help me to improve my code?

Comment: I saw your code, the implementation is correct, this is what I suggested. I'm glad it works for you. Now in regards to performance, I can't know which part is the cause. It is probably `mailSender.send` since this call is blocking and may take time, but I'll let you confirm that by profiling your job. If customers are not related (which should be the case I guess), try to use a multi-threaded or a partitioned step to improve performance (See this chapter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/scalability.html#scalability).